# WSDL Parser using Python3

Tags: web-services, python-3.x, soap, wsdl, python-3.4

I am wondering if there is an efficient library to parse WSDL files (e.g. extracting the WSDL elements and their contents) and compatible with Python3.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at suds-jurko: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.6 - it's a maintained version of the suds library and it has a WSDL parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SimeonVisser. suds-jurko worked fine with me.